# Limit login to web app to some specific devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-applications

I have created a Labor/Time Keeping application that is used for the Construction industry, and it consists of a WinForms Client where employees actually clock in and out, a WCF web service that fields the clock in and out events and provides data to the clients, and a back-end WinForms piece for Configuration, Administration and Reporting.  This is all .NET with C#.

I'm looking to also write an ASP.NET Web Client to make it more flexible, with the intent that this will be used from tablets and/or cell phones from the field.

So, now that the background is out of the way, here's a requirement that I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish.

I don't want employees to be able to just clock in and out from their house, or from their personal phones; they should be clocking in/out with a company owned device that the Foreman keeps in his truck for that specific purpose.  At the same time, I want logging in to the web app to be as simple as entering a 4 digit pin number and clicking either Clock IN or Clock OUT (no offense to the construction industy's employees, but there are some who literally have trouble trying to type in a username and password on a mobile device).

What is the best way to limit access to this web client to some specific set authorized of devices?  I've considered trying to MAC Address filter, and I read about using client certificates to limit which devices could access the web service, but is there any better way?  I mean, couldn't a client certificate just be copied to someone's personal phone if you get that rare concrete finisher who happens to be a nerd and know how to get it off of the company's device?

Is there any other way from a web app that you can uniquely identify a device and match it up with a list of authorized devices?

Comment: You could just give the foreman a username/password or pin he needs to input first before the webapp is even accessible.  Anything using MAC Addresses is vulnerable too. Another thought I just had was how are you going to prevent people from telling their friends their pin and have them clock in using it.

Comment: @Dharun I second your opinion of having the foreman log the system in first, this cuts down the worry of other people logging in from outside of the workzone. Pins do prove an issue with buddies logging each other in. I doubt you could get away with it but making them enter their SSN would probably stop people from having their friends log them in. I know I wouldn't give my friends or coworkers my SSN.

Comment: regardless of who logs in when, I want to still limit access to the site to certain devices, and need to know the best way to accomplish that

Comment: Well one way is to leave a persistent cookie on the device (which is basically what having the foreman authorize the device is doing. You could have someone else do it as well). Of course someone can steal the cookie off the device but they'd need access to it. If you think about Google Analytics the best way they've come up with uniquely identifying a device is this way.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.net you can't take the MAC address of client's network adapter. Because of that, you can not count on defining a white list of MAC addresses for 'valid' devices. But you can use some other tricks alternatively:

1- You can find out the IP address of your client devices and limit them if they are not authorized from your side.

2- You can Also detect OS, computer name and browser name and screen resolution and you may utilize them in this case.

3- You can keep a flag of how many cookies have you been set for a specific user and control in this way.

4- You may use Windows authentication to prevent your users from a form-based authentication (of course if your network is active directory based)

Comment: I think #1 and #4 aren't possible for my needs, since I need to support Android and IOS devices and they will probably be on cell networks so IP will probably change often.  I like the suggestion of taking OS, Computer Name and Screen Resolution though, and maybe some other attributes that I can access and making some kind of key out of those.  Its not super secure, but probably close enough for my needs.